# 100 Users in Exchange Online 365, Can their mailbox storage location be split across two regions?

Tags: exchange, exchangeonline, multi-tenancy

From my research I believe this is possible with Microsoft's 'Multigeo', but I believe this needs 5000 users, not 100. I do remember there are other ways around this, perhaps multi-tenants but then I'm unsure whether two tenants can be completely synchronized with the same domain name.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Company has two offices based in separate countries - due to company security/data policies they would like user mailboxes stored in the country where the staff member is located.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by [**Multi-Geo Capabilities in Exchange Online**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/multi-geo-capabilities-in-exchange-online).
We need to configure PreferredDataLocation attribute in **Azure AD**, for example:

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <UserPrincipalName> -PreferredDataLocation <GeoCode>
```

And, Yes, 5000 is the minimum limitation in one Office 365 tenant for this feature.